# ASP.NET MVC5 show exceptions error message in a label within a view possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

In classic ASP.NET i placed a label on the .aspx page and when an error was thrown, for example by an try ... catch block, i made the label visible and bound the error message to the labels `Text` property.

But in MVC this seems not to be possible. All examples which i found in the web are showing how to redirect to an dedicated error view. But i wanted to the error directly on the page where it happens or within a model dialog.

Is this possible and how to do this in MVC (4/5)?

Comment: Either create an error string property in the model for the page or more reasonably pass the message to the view with a ViewBag.

Comment: there are many ways to do that ... [here is a simple example to do](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xpq0UL)

Comment: show your model class'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the error message into a ViewBag and then show message in View.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    try 
    {           
        //Do something
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ViewBag.Error = e.Message;
    }
    return View();
}
```

**View**

```
@if(ViewBag.Error != null)
{
    <label>@ViewBag.Error</label>
}
```